# Recursive relation in the square root form.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I have been struggling to show the convergence and the limit value of the following recursive relation:

> $x_{n+2}=\sqrt{x_n x_{n+1}} $ with initial values $x_1=a$ and $x_2=b$ for $0<a<b<\infty$

I showed by induction that $ x_{2n-1}<x_{2n+1}<x_{2n+2}<x_{2n}$. I know that if I could show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{2n}-x_{2n-1}=0$, then this implies convergence. However, I could not see the pattern. Moreover, I could not find the actual limit either. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Let $y_n = \log x_n$, it satisfies a linear recurrence relation
$$y_{n+2} = \frac12(y_{n+1} + y_n)$$
The corresponding characteristic equation has the form
$$\lambda^2 - \frac12(\lambda + 1) = 0\quad\iff\quad (\lambda-1)(\lambda+\frac12) = 0$$ 
This implies the general solution of $y_n$ has the from $y_n = A + B (-\frac12)^n$ for some constants $A,B$. Solving this with the initial condition $(x_1,x_2) = (a,b)$ gives you a closed form expression of $x_n$:

$$x_n = (ab^2)^{\frac13}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac13(-\frac12)^{n-2}}
\quad\implies\quad \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n =
(ab^2)^{\frac13}$$